# Get List of dates between two date Range by Product

Tags: sql

Thank you for taking your time to read this through

I have a table as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ArYu.png)

I need to transform the above table into table below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu31P.png)

How do I achieve this.

Thank you in advance

Cheers

Comment: Can you please post your table examples as text and not as images?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far to try and get what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have one option:

Create an additional table "dates" and fill it with the neccesary dates then you can get your data from a SELECT like this:

```
SELECT P.ProductID, D.Date FROM products as P
JOIN dates as D ON D.Date BETWEEN P.From AND P.To
```

Comment: I needed to create a primary key by concatnating the ProductID and the dates column so that I could link it to my sales table.

The first table (Untransformed) is our sales promotion table and products in that sales promotion table attracts a certain % discount for the given period. I need to calculate that discount in sales table by looking up Product Promotion Table with From and To date.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you mean, can you send an example?

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you for you response and apologies for the delay